# Cannot Mount external harddrive

Tags: mount

Trying to plug it in, and here is the error:
Unable to mount My Passport
Error creating mount point `/media/jianyue/My Passport': Read-only file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that '/media/jianyue' exists. I assume that jianyue is your username. Ubuntu seems to have a bug in that they now want to mount these removable drives in /media/'username' but it does not automatically create it...

So, I think this should work for anyone for their own user account:

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/$USER
$ sudo chown $USER.$USER /media/$USER
```

You would need to have administration privileges to be able to do execute these commands. You should end up with the directory /media/jianyue created and owned by jianyue.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried the commands. It works, after I have placed " sudo chown $USER.$USER /media/$USER" I wonder what it does.